# Cannot establish SSL/TLS connection between Kong 0.10.x and datastore postgresql-9.6

Tags: postgresql, ssl, lua, tls1.2, kong

I am using Kong 10.x with datastore postgresql 9.6.
I want to establish ssl connection between kong and it's datastore postgresql.
But I get the following errors:

## Postgresql Error:

```
LOG:  could not accept SSL connection: tlsv1 alert unknown ca
```

## Error from kong:

```
/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/cmd/migrations.lua:34: [postgres error] could not retrieve current migrations: [postgres error] connection refused
```

Below are my Kong and Postgresql Configurations:

### Kong:

```
# Kong configuration file
# DATASTORE
database = postgres                
pg_host = 10.0.1.191
pg_port = 5432
pg_user = kong
pg_password = kong
pg_database = kong    
pg_ssl = on    
pg_ssl_verify = on

# DEVELOPMENT & MISCELLANEOUS
lua_ssl_trusted_certificate = /opt/postgres_ssl/postgresql.crt  # Absolute path to the certificate
```

### Postgresql:

## pg_hba.conf:

```
hostssl all         all    10.0.1.191/32             md5 clientcert=1
```

## postgresql.conf:

```
listen_addresses = '10.0.1.191'
ssl_cert_file = 'server.crt'
ssl_key_file = 'server.key'
ssl_ca_file = 'root.crt'
```

### Certificate Generation Procedure:

```
openssl genrsa -passout pass:mypass -des3 -out server.key 1024
openssl rsa -passin pass:mypass -in server.key -out server.key
chmod 400 server.key
openssl req -new -key server.key -days 3650 -out server.crt -x509 -subj '/C=IN/ST=Maharastra/L=Mumbai/O=Development/CN=10.0.1.191'
cp server.crt root.crt
openssl genrsa -passout pass:iotadmin -des3 -out postgresql.key 1024
openssl rsa -in postgresql.key -out postgresql.key -passin pass:mypass
openssl req -new -key postgresql.key -days 3650 -out postgresql.csr -subj '/C=IN/ST=Maharastra/L=Mumbai/O=Development/CN=kong'
openssl x509 -req -in postgresql.csr -CA root.crt -CAkey server.key -out postgresql.crt -CAcreateserial
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that Kong doesn't trust the CA which signed the certificate of the database. This doesn't surprise much, because it only knows the latter, but not the certificate of the CA.

Try using the root certificate for your `lua_ssl_trusted_certificate` config entry and it should work:

```
lua_ssl_trusted_certificate = /path/to/your/root.crt
```